# Power BI - Filter Table by Interquartile Range Measure Dynamically

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, iqr

I have the following table. I cannot show the activities, but essentially I have a list of activities and several metrics of the activity duration (count, sum, min, max, median, average, and upper interquartile range). The data has heavy outliers as you can see in the table below:

[image]

I created a measure to calculate IQR and the upper and lower bounds. I need to develop a slicer now that filters this table to remove any datapoints where duration exceeds the upper IQR. My goal is to develop a new average per activity of what the proper duration should be for the given activity.

The IQR calculations are measures. I tried to create a calculated column (Duration > IQR Lower and Duration < IQE Upper) but Power BI does not allow calculated columns to reference measures. I tried it the other way as well and it did not work. I think my best bet is a calculated table but I'm not sure how to do it.